# Is there something like flatTap in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Is there something like flatTap in RxJS? If no, why? Would it be "bad practice"?

Suppose you want to tap something and automatically subscribe (an) inner observable(s) - similar as with flatMap -  but you want to keep the same object for further piping. Then I see myself sometimes do something like this:

```
outerObservable.pipe(
  flatMap(v => {
    return createInnerObservables(v).pipe(
      toArray(),
      map(() => v),
    );
  }),
  map(v => do something with v),
)...
```

With a flatTap operator this could simplify to:

```
outerObservable.pipe(
  flatTap(v => createInnerObservables(v)),
  map(v => do something with v),
)...
```

Comment: Who would be cleaning up that subscription? I think it's just more explicit to do `tap(v => createInnerObservables(v).subscribe())`, at least it makes it clear there's a dangling subscription that might not get ever cleaned up. You can create this operator for your own use, but I wouldn't add it as an official one in rxjs.

Comment: Another issue is naming: `flatMap` first maps values to observables, then flattens the resulting Observable<Observable<V>> to Observable<V>. It's essentiall the same as doing a `map(v => observable)` followed by a `mergeAll()`. The name `flatTap` doesn't make sense if we try to follow this logic

Comment: *'Would it be "bad practice"?'*. Basically yes. I'm not saying you **never** want to do this, but it's enough of a red flag that you should probably just explicitly subscribe inside `tap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use a `subject` to setup the side effect

```
let doSideEffect=new Subject();
outerObservable.pipe(
  tap(v => doSideEffect.next(v)),
  map(v => do something with v),
)...
// you can handle when to unsubscribe/complete the stream
doSideEffect.asObservable().pipe(....)
```